# How could I use a custom distance metric for KNeighboursRegressor?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm trying to apply my own custom distance metric function when using knn regression model.
My dataset is a mixture of nominal, ordinal, numeric and binary types of fields

Code:

```python
def cus_distance(array1, array2, **kwargs):
    # calculate the distance, return a float
    pass

knn = neighbors.KNeighborsRegressor(weights='distance', metric=cus_distance)

# train_data is a pandas dataframe obj
knn.fit(train_data.ix[:, fields_list], train_data['time_costs'])
```

The last line will cause an exception:

```python
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-284-04520b227b8a> in <module>()
----> 1 knn.fit(train_data.ix[:, fields_list], train_data['time_costs'])

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/neighbors/base.pyc in fit(self, X, y)
    587             X, y = check_arrays(X, y, sparse_format="csr")
    588         self._y = y
--> 589         return self._fit(X)
    590 
    591 

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/neighbors/base.pyc in _fit(self, X)
    214             self._tree = BallTree(X, self.leaf_size,
    215                                   metric=self.effective_metric_,
--> 216                                   **self.effective_metric_kwds_)
    217         elif self._fit_method == 'kd_tree':
    218             self._tree = KDTree(X, self.leaf_size,

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/neighbors/ball_tree.so in sklearn.neighbors.ball_tree.BinaryTree.__init__ (sklearn/neighbors/ball_tree.c:7983)()

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/numeric.pyc in asarray(a, dtype, order)
    318 
    319     """
--> 320     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
    321 
    322 def asanyarray(a, dtype=None, order=None):

ValueError: could not convert string to float: Unknown
```

I know this error caused by string values(the 'Unknown' is one of them) in my dataset.
This confused me, in my understanding, the function cus_distance should take care of these str values, and the KNeighborsRegressor just use the return value of my function.

Q:
 * Is this the right way to use a custom defined distance metric in KNN Regression?
 * If it is, why I met this exception?
 * If not, what is the right way?

Comment: So what does it return if you hit an 'Unknown'?

Comment: @IvoFlipse Does this "it" mean the function cus_distance?

Comment: Yes, that was what I was referring to. But it seems @jakevdp already provided an answer

Comment: @IvoFlipse In the function cus_distance, I deal str values, which are considered as nominal type, and int values, considered as numeric type, and other values with different ways, to calculate the dissimilarity between two records.

Answer (score 4):

The Ball Tree and KD Tree require floating point data, regardless of the metric used.  If your data cannot be converted to floating point, then you will get this sort of error.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> data = [1, "Unknown", 2]
>>> np.asarray(data, dtype=float)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
----> 1 np.asarray(data, dtype=float)

ValueError: could not convert string to float: Unknown
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @jakevdp .
The scikit-learn supports Brute Force, Ball Tree and KD Tree, and according to @jakevdp 's answer, the only one I can use is Brute Force algorighm, so my code change to:

```python
knn = neighbors.KNeighborsRegressor(weights='distance', metric=cus_distance, algorithm='brute')
knn.fit(train_data.ix[:, fields_list], train_data['time_costs'])
```

This time it won't raise error anymore, **Thanks jakevdp!**

But new question came, when I try to use this knn object:

```
knn.predict(check_data.ix[:, fields_list])
```

this will cause a same error in my question. So I look into the scikit-learn's source code, found **[this line](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/metrics/pairwise.py#L887)** cause this error:

```python
elif callable(metric):
    # Check matrices first (this is usually done by the metric).
    X, Y = check_pairwise_arrays(X, Y)
    n_x, n_y = X.shape[0], Y.shape[0]
```

the function check_pairwise_arrays will try to convert all values to float, "Unknown" cause the error again.

I think this is kind of bug, because scikit's builtin metrics don't support mixture types of dataset, I write a customer metric function, but this line still force the dataset to be  pure float type.
And as the comment above this line said, the checking works should be done by customer metrics, **so I just commented this line**, reload this module, my knn object can work perfectly now :)

ps: I'm working on pushing this change to the scikit-learn official github repo.

Comment: This is not a bug. This ensures correct behavior in a number of settings. Using pandas dataframes is not supported by sklearn. I think it should be fairly simple to write your own KNN for your setting.