# Does BallTree support customized metric with irregular data now?

Tags: numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have a dataset describing some traces in following form:

```
traceId1: event1 time1 event2 time2 ... eventN timeN
traceId2: event1 time1 event2 time2 ... eventM-1 timeM-1 eventM timeM
.
.
.
```

Namely, this file contains several traces. Each trace consists of several events and the time at which these event happens. The length of each trace may vary. Thus I can't transform the data into a matrix.

I wrote a class Point to hold each trace as an object. I also wrote a customized function to compute the distance between each pair of trace. When I try to build a BallTree with my metric, it gives:

```
  File "/home/yangzhao/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py", line 474, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)

TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Point'
```

Based on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20655287/how-could-i-use-a-customer-distance-metric-for-kneighboursregressor?newreg=667d0ee8f0724b9eb2a39dfaa243725a), it seems BallTree only accept datatypes which can be transformed into float. Since this is posted in 2013, is there any workaround now? For example, write a **float** method in the class definition?

PS:I can write a BallTree in Python by myself, but it's not optimized thus works slowly. And the system limits the maximum depth of recursion so it can't work on my full dataset. I've also implemented the BallTree in C++, is it a good idea to call that function in Python instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Ball Tree will only work with data that can be formed into a 2D floating point array. You can see this in the initialization of the object [in the source code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/neighbors/binary_tree.pxi#L1053). I do not anticipate that the codebase will be changed to support arrays of custom objects.

In any case, due to the limitations of the Python callbacks used, a custom distance metric will not be very performant. If you have other C++ code that works for your problem, it's relatively straightforward to wrap it for use in Python using, e.g. [cython](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/wrapping_CPlusPlus.html).